# await thousands of Tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an application which converts some data often there are 1.000 - 30.000 files.

I need to do 3 steps:

1. copy a File (replace some text in there)
2. Make a Webrequest with WebClient to download a file (I send the copied file to a WebServer, which converts the file to another format)
3. Take the downloaded file and change some of the content

So all three steps include some I/O and I used async/await methods:

```
var tasks = files.Select(async (file) =>
{
    Item item = await createtempFile(file).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await convert(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await clean(item).ConfigureAwait(false);
}).ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I don´t know if this is the best practice, because I create more than thousand tasks. I thought about splitting the three steps like:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
var tasks = files.Select(async (file) =>
{
    Item item = await createtempFile(file, ext).ConfigureAwait(false);
    lock(items)
        items.Add(item);
}).ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

var tasks = items.Select(async (item) =>
{
    await convert(item, baseAddress, ext).ConfigureAwait(false);
}).ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

var tasks = items.Select(async (item) =>
{
    await clean(targetFile, item.Doctype, ext).ConfigureAwait(false);
}).ToList();

await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But that doesn´t seem to be better or faster, because I create 3 times thousands of tasks.

Should I throttle the creation of tasks? Like chunks of 100 tasks?
Or am I just overthinking it and the creation of thousands of tasks is just fine.

The CPU is idling with 2-4% peak, so I thought about too many awaits or context switches.

Maybe the WebRequest calls are too many, because the WebServer/WebService can´t handle thousands of Requests simultaneously and I should only throttle the WebRequests?

I already increased the .NET maxconnection in the app.config file.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You can use `Parallel.ForEach` to automatically distribute parallel works. Parallel.ForEach include Partitioner to avoid making more tasks than necessary.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The question is at the bottom, is this the best practice to create thousand of tasks or shall I throttle them.
Parallel.ForEach performs well for CPU bound work, but I got I/O bound work.
If I use Parallel.ForEach, the CPU is at 80-90%, but the whole application is as fast as the async/await variant.

Comment: `await` does not implicitly mean you start threads and work in parallel. So I think you have to rethink your idea and make it a real threaded application.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan Parallel.Foreach is for CPU bound work and not for IO bound work.

Comment: @ckruczek I know, but it is working in parallel, I can see that the files are created and downloaded in parallel. Because of the ConfigureAwait(false), the tasks can run in parallel. At least this is what I understood from posts from SO and codeproject.

Comment: Yes, you are overthinking it. Tasks are not threads. They are small and cheap wrappers and 'thousands' is peanuts.

Comment: @HenkHolterman That would be nice, can you maybe provide a link or some more explanation about many tasks and awaits?

Comment: I agree with Henk. I see no problem with your current approach. This is eaxctly what Tasks are for: waiting for I/O and scheduling that for you. Until you give LongRunning flag, Tasks will share threads between them. If you use Default scheduler, they will run on N threads on the threadpool, so even the thread count is managed for you according to current machine setup. If tasks are very long, you can actually starve the thread pool with them, it doesnt need to be a problem. But if it is, you can also implement your own pool and scheduler.

Comment: Yeah, already remove that last comment.

Comment: I briefly tred but failed to find how much a Task costs, but it's almost just a piece of data that describes the work. If there is anything heavy, it's in the final threads that process them (and the danger of creating too many), and in the Scheduler that manages it (if it complicated or has inefficient code). Out of the box you get a few choices only, but there are more schedulers available separately - http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/specialized-task-schedulers-in-net-4-par/228800428

Comment: If you want to optimize it further, and if you suspect the scheduling to be a problem, you can start experimenting if one of them works better than default in your case. Only a few of them sound reasonable of course. Then, finally, you can look at the source of this library (->GitHub) and see one of the schedulers and copy&paster&edit and create your own scheduler.

Comment: re `The CPU is idling with 2-4% peak, so I thought about too many awaits or context switches` - CPU is one thing, but how's the I/O? Is it saturated, or is it idling as well? if it is saturated, well, then CPU idles because it waits  for the data, no surprises. "Case closed" (or actually, not. Now go and checkif you can improve the IO). But **if neither** CPU nor IO is running at peak, then something other is limiting the speed.. you may try snapshotting and checking stacktraces to see where the actual threads sit.

Comment: Snapshoting stacktraces can often show you if they are sitting in the scheduling (huh? pool starved?) or in I/O ops (huh? IO as not saturated, so strange) or on whatelse, and that will tell you at leastwhy CPU is idle, like "I left debugging Thread.Sleep(1000)" (happened to me a few times)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commenters have correctly noted, you're overthinking it. The .NET runtime has absolutely no problem tracking thousands of tasks.

However, you might want to consider using a TPL Dataflow pipeline, which would enable you to easily have different concurrency levels for different operations ("blocks") in your pipeline.

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to execute **async operations in parallel** with **limiting** the number of concurrent operations. There is a cool extension method for that, it is **not part of the .Net framework**.

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerates a collection in parallel and calls an async method on each item. Useful for making 
/// parallel async calls, e.g. independent web requests when the degree of parallelism needs to be
/// limited.
/// </summary>
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int degreeOfParalellism, Func<T, Task> action)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(degreeOfParalellism).Select(partition => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (partition)
            while (partition.MoveNext())
                await action(partition.Current);
    })));
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var files = new List<string> {"one", "two", "three"};
await files.ForEachAsync(5, async file =>
{
   // do async stuff here with the file
   await Task.Delay(1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn´t know this kind of implementation. I always used SemaphoreSlim with the size I want to throttle my work.