# Running async function in parallel using LINQ's AsParallel()

Tags: async-await, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Document DB repository class that has one get method like below:

```
private static DocumentClient client;
public async Task<TEntity> Get(string id, string partitionKey = null)
{
    try
    {
        RequestOptions requestOptions = null;
        if (partitionKey != null)
        {
            requestOptions = new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey) };
        }

        var result = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId, id),
            requestOptions);
        return (TEntity)(dynamic)result.Resource;
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException e)
    {
        // Have logic for different exceptions actually
        throw;
    }
}
```

I have two collections - Collection1 and Collection2. Collection1 is non-partitioned whereas Collection2 is partitioned.

On the client side, I create two repository objects, one for each collection.

```
private static DocumentDBRepository<Collection1Item> collection1Repository = new DocumentDBRepository<Collection1Item>("Collection1");
private static DocumentDBRepository<Collection2Item> collection2Repository = new DocumentDBRepository<Collection2Item>("Collection2");

List<Collection1Item> collection1Items = await collection1Repository.GetItemsFromCollection1(); // Selects first forty documents based on time

List<UIItem> uiItems = new List<UIItem>();
foreach (var item in collection1Items)
{
    var collection2Item = await storageRepository.Get(item.Collection2Reference, item.TargetId);    // TargetId is my partition key for Collection2
    uiItems.Add(new UIItem
    {
        ItemId = item.ItemId,
        Collection1Reference = item.Id,
        TargetId = item.TargetId,        
        Collection2Reference = item.Collection2Reference,
        Value = collection2Item.Value
    });
}
```

This works fine. But since it is happening sequentially with foreach, I wanted to do those Get calls in parallel. When I do it in parallel as below:

```
ConcurrentBag<UIItem> uiItems = new ConcurrentBag<UIItem>();
collection1Items.AsParallel().ForAll(async item => {
    var collection2Item = await storageRepository.Get(item.Collection2Reference, item.TargetId);    // TargetId is my partition key for Collection2
    uiItems.Add(new UIItem
    {
        ItemId = item.ItemId,
        Collection1Reference = item.Id,
        TargetId = item.TargetId,        
        Collection2Reference = item.Collection2Reference,
        Value = collection2Item.Value
    });
  }
);
```

It doesn't work and ***uiItems*** is always empty.

Comment: This code doesn't compile - you do not mark lambda as `async`, so you can't use `await` inside it. Apart from that, your code looks correct, and should work. Be more specific.

Comment: You don't need `Parallel.For` to run async operations concurrently, if they are truly asynchronous they *already* run concurrently. You could collect the task returned from each operation and simply call `await Task.WhenAll()` on all the tasks.

Comment: :) yeah, that's what I suggested too.

Comment: @MiklósTóth that's not what you suggested. Check the comment to your answer

Comment: @VMAtm: Yes I do have async qualifier for the lambda expression. Corrected the expression in the post. Thank you for pointing it out. To be more specific about the problem, it never hits the "uiItems.Add" line with the parallel loop and hence it's always empty.

Comment: @vmn Are you sure you aren't getting any exceptions with access exception? According to your code, you're trying to access `UIItems` from the background thread.

Comment: @VMAtm: No I don't get any exceptions. I access UIItems only if its Count is greater than zero. If it's zero, I just print a warning message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need Parallel.For to run async operations concurrently. If they are truly asynchronous they already run concurrently.

You could collect the task returned from each operation and simply call await Task.WhenAll() on all the tasks. If you modify your lambda to create and return a UIItem, the result of `await Task.WhenAll()` will be a collection of UIItems. No need to modify global state from *inside* the concurrent operations.

For example:

```
var itemTasks = collection1Items.Select(async item =>
    {
        var collection2Item = await storageRepository.Get(item.Collection2Reference, item.TargetId);    
        return new UIItem
        {
            ItemId = item.ItemId,
            Collection1Reference = item.Id,
            TargetId = item.TargetId,        
            Collection2Reference = item.Collection2Reference,
            Value = collection2Item.Value
        }
    });

var results= await Task.WhenAll(itemTasks);
```

A word of caution though - this will fire *all* `Get` operations concurrently. That may not be what you want, especially when calling a service with rate limiting.

Comment: About limiting the number of concurrent tasks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124360/await-thousands-of-tasks/40125835#40125835

Comment: @MiklósTóth there are better options, like *not* generating thousands of tasks but using TPL Dataflow or Reactive Extensions to control the number of concurrent tasks and even the rate. There's no need to partition the data. ForEachAsync wasn't created to rate limit tasks

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: On your caution of firing all Get calls concurrently, I do need to take care not to throttle the service. Is it just better to use **_foreach_** in that case?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I totally agree with the TPL way. But, in my opinion, it can't be used for every use cases. Sometimes you just want to work with a small bunch of tasks you want to parallelize and PLINQ is a very good tool for that. But, clearly here (a bunch of task to call a DB) i would recommend using TPL. the number of tasks that'll be coming can't be managed easily, you could handle it through TPL ActionBlock for example.

Comment: @Rayyyz no it's not - PLINQ is meant for data parallelism, not start some tasks. PLINQ will partition the data and use a fixed number of workers to process it. That costs. If you wanted to create some tasks from data, you can use LINQ and call `Task.Run` in the `Select` call. If you want to throttle, the TPL DataFlow classes allow setting a specific DOP

Answer (score 1):

Try simply starting tasks and waiting for all of them at the end. That would result in parallel execution.

```
var tasks = collection1Items.Select(async item =>
{
    //var collection2Item = await storageRepository.Get...
    return new UIItem
    {
        //...
    };
});

var uiItems = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

PLINQ is useful when working with in-memory constructs and using as many threads as possible, but if used with the async-await technique (which is for releasing threads while accessing external resources), you can end up with strange results.

Comment: If you await the task, you don't have to and shouldn't try to modify `uiItems`. Return a `Task<UIItem>` and store the result of `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to get the results

Comment: Well, technically it does not hurt, because uiItems is a concurrent bag, but in this particular case it would be better what you suggest, yes.

Comment: It hurts. ConcurrentBag is a *specialized* container that offers fast thread-local storage. Trying to access data from a different thread's storage is expensive. It's not the same as eg a ConcurrentDictionary or ConcurrentCollection.

Comment: Updated the answer with a more compact solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share a solution for an issue i saw in some comments.

If you're scared about thread rate limit, and you want to limit this by yourself, you can do something like this, using [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0).

```
var nbCores = Environment.ProcessorCount;
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(nbCores, nbCores);

var processTasks = items.Select(async x =>
{
   await semaphore.WaitAsync();
   try
   {
     await ProcessAsync();
   }
   finally
   {
     semaphore.Release();
   }
});

await Task.WhenAll(processTasks);
```

In this example, i called concurrently my "ProcessAsync" but limited to {processor number} concurrent processes.

Hope that's help someone.

NB : You could set the "nbCores" variable as a proper value that satisfy your code condition, of course.

NB 2 : This example is for some use cases, not all of them. I would highly suggest with a big load of task to refer to [TPL programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)